# How do I attach a PATH in a created ID jpeg when I SaveAs with toBlob in js?

Tags: javascript

I have "canvas-toBlob.js" and "FileSaver.js".

The PATH of saveAs is the automatic "Temp" folder but I want the PATH in the js to be what I wanted name it to. This is part of the code that I have problems with:

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) { saveAs(blob, hrjpeg); }, "image/jpeg");

I get the automatic temporary PATH when I run this (C:\Users\xxxx\App\Local\Temp") but what won't is to name the PATH "D:_Media\2019\july\thumbnail".
Is there a way to make the saveAs to do the PATH? Or if that can't be done, is there a different way for me to save a PATH + filename?

Thanks.